# The use of the phrase "might I say/do something" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/rY9zHNOjGrs). It is at around 14 second.

> We will not be describing battles and tactics. If that is your bag, **might I suggest** Ken Burns....

I cannot get whether the host asks for permission to suggest the author or it is some kind of emphatic phrase that I cannot get the meaning in the context.

Comment: This is a politeness hedge; the speaker hasn't been asked for a suggestion, so he phrases the suggestion tentatively--as you say, "asks for permission".

Comment: By the way, Ken Burns isn't an author.  He's a documentary film maker who made films such as *The Civil War*, *The War*, *The Vietnam War*, as well as non-war documentaries like *Baseball*, *Jazz* and *The National Parks: America's Best Idea*

Comment: @StoneyB That comment would make a great answer!